# Month view - full hours are only displayed 9 instead of 09:00

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i just can't figure out how to change the following problem. When i have an event that starts at 09:00 it is shown correctly in the agendaWeek and the agendaDay. But on the month view it is shown as 9 only. How can i display the full time here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [timeFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/) option.

```
timeFormat: 'hh:mm a'
```

would change it to a 12 hour clock (09:00 am).

```
timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
```

for a 24 hour clock.

fullcalendar uses momentjs for it's dates. Formatting rules are [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/qp6Lxshp/1/)